# Trying To Read In File With C++ But Not Working

Tags: c++, file, ubuntu, io

In the following code I am simply trying to open a file and print it's contents:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    std::ifstream fin;
    fin.open("ride");

    string line;
     while (fin >> line)
    {
      std::cout << "I am here" << std::endl;
      cout << line << endl;
    }
    fin.close();

    return 0;
}
```

however no matter what I do this program is not entering the while loop....why?

I am running Ubuntu 14.04, the file has the name 'ride', it is located in my home directory and my source file which happens to be 'main.cpp' is also located in my home directory, in addition the cursor is placed at the beginning of the file 'ride'. I have tried changing file name to 'ride.txt' and using absolute paths but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Is there anything in the file?

Comment: yes, there are 5 words, one per line

Comment: i'm quite sure open returns false, and they are in the same directory

Comment: @fYre What do you mean `open` returns false? `open` shouldn't have a return value.

Comment: I was able to run your code exactly as posted (congratulations! That's rare on SO). It read the file just fine. I think it's not succeeding in opening your file for some reason (location, permissions, etc.)

Comment: @fYre Check `fin`'s state flags.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if its open, but I used a debugger and 'fin >> line' returns false

Comment: @Daniel You have right. `open` doesn't return anything. After `open` you should call `is_open`.

Comment: Is it possible that you have opened the file somewhere else (an editor ?) and that the file is locked for this reason ?

Comment: `fin >> line` doesn't return `bool`. It returns reference to `fin`. [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/)

Comment: how to check fin's status flag? Also I just added the try and catch statemet by the deleted answer and the message in the catch statement was not displayed

Comment: @NO_NAME I'm assuming it was implicitly converted to a bool

Comment: Your program is perfectly fine (except you should check and report errors). Hiw do you run it?

Comment: I tried running in an IDE called Clion

Comment: @fYre Read about checking stream states here [std::ifstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) under **State functions**. The implicit `bool` conversion you mention, actually retrieves the same state as `fin.good()`.

Comment: Try to print result of `realpath("/proc/self/exe", nullptr);`. It returns current directory of the program. Is it the directory which contains file "ride"? **EDIT:** The function needs `cstdlib` and `climits`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Almost. According to [a logic table on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool), it returns the equivalent of `!failbit && !badbit`, while `good()` also takes `eofbit` into account.

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter one bit where your source file is located, as your source file is not being executed.

`file` must be in the *current working directory* of the shell from which you've run your program.

Furthermore, if you've tried absolute paths and it still doesn't work then your permissions are insufficient.

There is nothing wrong with the code you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

Probably current working directory of your program is not the directory which contains your file.

To prevent this, you can:

1. Use path relative to the current working directory. (for example '../src/bar')
2. Use function `chdir` to set current working directory at runtime.
3. Use full path of you file. (for example '/home/foo/Desktop/bar')
4. If you use development environment, you can set current working directory in options.